# How to change color of clicked recyclerview row?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app to show notices posted on my college website by parsing rss feed.I'm using recyclerview with each row as a cardview. The cardview contains  two textviews,one to show notice title and other to show published date. When user clicks a cardview a new activity is opened showing details of that particular notice. I want when a card view is clicked,its background color should change to grey marking that the particular item is read already.

I have used an ArrayList to store the positions of the clicked items and checking in onBindViewHolder method if the position(the argument of the onBindViewHolder) is present in the ArrayList. If it is then change the background color to grey.

But the problem is if I click a card view and then I scroll down-up-down, the color of some other random cardviews also get changed.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<NoticeItem> noticeItems;
    Context ctx;
    // ArrayList to store positions of clicked items
    ArrayList<Integer> clickedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<NoticeItem> noticeItems,Context ctx) {
        this.noticeItems = noticeItems;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.notice_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new CardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int position) {

        cardViewHolder.title.setText(noticeItems.get(position).getTitle());
        cardViewHolder.pubDate.setText(noticeItems.get(position).getDate());

        // checking if array list contains the current position
        if(clickedItems.contains(position))
        {
            cardViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Log.i("Text",cardViewHolder.title.getText().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noticeItems.size();
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title,pubDate;
        CardView cardView;
        public CardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url",noticeItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).link);
                    ctx.startActivity(intent);
                    // adding clicked item position to the array list
                    clickedItems.add(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            pubDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should also reset the color to normal

try this

```
if(clickedItems.contains(position)) {
    cardViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
} else {
    cardViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: that works fine bro :)  But could you explain why was that happening..if I've not written else part then it should do nothing, why it was changing color of random cardviews?

Comment: @sumit the recyclerview recycles the viewholders so you have to reset the color

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int currentSelectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;


   viewHolder.rl_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    currentSelectedPosition = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            if (currentSelectedPosition == position) {
                  // change color
            } else {

            }
```